# Proving surjectivity of a function between stabilizer groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I am working on proving that a certain function is bijective. I think I have proven the injectivity aspect however I'm having troubles proving surjectivity. Let $X$ be a set, $i \in X$ and say that $\sigma \in S_X$ fixes. I am given the following two sets of functions:

$P_i = \{\sigma \in S_X \ | \ \sigma(i) = i)\}$

$P_j = \{\sigma \in S_X \ | \ \sigma(j) = j)\}$

as well as the function $f: S_X \rightarrow S_X$ defined by $f(\sigma) = \rho \circ \sigma \circ \rho^{-1}$, where $\rho(i) = j$ for some $j$.

I am trying to prove that $f$ is a bijection between $P_i$ and $P_j$.

My attempt is as follows:

$\underline{\text{Injectivity}}$: Suppose $f(\sigma) = f(\tau)$; then $\rho \circ \sigma \circ \rho^{-1} = \rho \circ \tau \circ \rho^{-1}$.

$\rho^{-1} \circ (\rho \circ \sigma \circ \rho^{-1}) = \rho^{-1} \circ (\rho \circ \tau \circ \rho^{-1})$

$(\rho^{-1} \circ \rho \circ \sigma) \circ \rho^{-1} = (\rho^{-1} \circ \rho \circ \tau) \circ \rho^{-1}$.

$\sigma \circ \rho^{-1} = \tau \circ \rho^{-1}$.

$\sigma \circ \rho^{-1} \circ \rho = \tau \circ \rho^{-1} \circ \rho$.

$\sigma = \tau $.

$\underline{\text{Surjectivity}}$: Let $\sigma \in S_X$. Then, given some $\tau \in S_X$, we have it that $f(\tau) = \rho \circ \tau \circ \rho^{-1}$. I am unsure though how to show that $f(\tau) = \sigma$. Any help would be appreciated here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to show a function is a bijection is to exhibit an inverse. First you should verify that conjugation $\varphi_{\rho}(\sigma)=\rho\sigma\rho^{-1}$ actually sends $P_i$ into $P_j$. Then, symmetrically, since $\rho^{-1}(j)=i$ that means $\varphi_{\rho^{-1}}$ sends $P_j$ into $P_i$. Then simply verify $\varphi_\rho$ and $\varphi_{\rho^{-1}}$ are inverses.

Comment: Haven't I shown that $f$ ``conjugates", to use your word, by showing that $f$ is injective? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Also, is it also sufficient to show that a bijection between two sets $A,B$ exists if there exist injective functions $f,g$ such from $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $A$ (respectively)?

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether A function is a bijection iff it has an *inverse*. While it is sufficient to show there are injections both ways, I am using the stronger fact that there is an inverse. I don't understand what you're asking me in your first comment. What part of my answer would you like clarified further?

Comment: Wait, can't a function have an inverse but not be bijective? Consider $f(x) = x +1$, where $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you think the inverse of that is? There is no inverse $\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z$. You must remember to keep track of domain and codomain appropriately. A function cannot have a (two-sided) inverse and not be bijective. If you're inexperienced or this isn't obvious to you, I suggest you try proving it. Specifically: if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are such that $(f\circ g):B\to B$ and $(g\circ f):A\to A$ are the identity maps then $f$ and $g$ are bijections.

Comment: You claimed that a function is bijective iff it has an inverse. I understand it to be the case that I have produced an example of an injective function which has an inverse yet it is not bijective (since $| \mathbb{Z}| < |\mathbb{R}|$.

Comment: Again, *what do you think the inverse function is*? If I press you hard enough, maybe you'll say it's $g(x)=x-1$, but that is *not a function* $\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z$. Like I said, you **must remember to keep track of domain and codomain**.

Comment: I see now, yes you are quite right and I am mistaken.